# Is it possible to load a jar into neo4j without restarting the server?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is it possible to load a jar into neo4j without restarting the server?

I would like to be able to deploy new jars without affecting upptime of other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do that, but it should NOT to do that on the production.

Neo4j doesn't support that by default, but there is a JVM way how to do that.

What you are looking for is a hot swapping. You can do that by your own with custom class loader or you can use existing solutions for that (I don't if they will work with Neo4j).

http://www.hotswapagent.org/
http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/